# Allow user to update/delete certain policies(Hashicorp Vault)

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

**Description**
I am using Hashicorp's Vault ,version 1.7.0, free version.

I would like to allow a certain range of policies that a user can assign/delete to a group. In that way he can add or delete entities user to the group from the UI.

**What I have done**

Bellow is written into blocks the overall policy file.

```
{
capabilities = ["list"]
}

#To show the identity endpoint from the UI
path "/identity/*"{
 capabilities = ["list" ]
}

#policies that I would like the user to have the ability to #assign to the group.

path "/sys/policies/acl/it_team_leader"{
capabilities = ["read", "update", "list"]
}

path "sys/policies/acl/it_user"{
capabilities = ["read", "update","list"]
}

path "sys/policies/acl/ui_settings"{
capabilities = ["read", "update", "list"]
}

path "sys/policies/acl/personal_storage"{
capabilities = ["read", "update","list"]
}

#Group id that the user have full access

path "/identity/group/id/2c97485a-754f-657a-5a8b-62b08a3ce8cb" {

capabilities = ["sudo","read","update","create","list"]
}
```

**What is the issue**
Lets assume that I have an super-privileged policy that provides access to the the whole secret engine.

From the UI I am able to assign to that group the super-priveleged policy and basically allow a restricted user to assign this super policy to the whole group.

When I extended the policy with :

```
path "sys/policies/acl/**super-priveleged**" {
capabilities = ["deny"]
}
```

is just restricting the policy to be read from the UI.

Appending the group path with allowed_parameters such us :

```
capabilities = ["sudo","read","update","create","list"]
denied_parameters = {
"policies" = ["it_user","it_team_leader",etc]

}
```

I receive a permission denied error(403).
Appending with denied parameters :

```
path "/identity/group/id/2c97485a-754f-657a-5a8b-62b08a3ce8cb" {

capabilities = ["sudo","read","update","create","list"]
denied_parameters = {
"policies" = ["super-policy"]

}
```

is not functioning and I am still allowed to assign the super policy.

I also tried wildcards with the same result.

Is it even possible to restrict one/a range of policies that can be assigned from the Vault UI?

Thanks in advance if you made it so far.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, to restrict user to update certain policies the allowed parameters fields should encapsulate a list and add an asterisk key with an empty list.

**Note** : The order of the policies assigned from the UI should comply with the order that is written in the .hcl file.

```
path "/identity/group/id/2c97485a-754f-657a-5a8b-62b08a3ce8cb"
{

capabilities = ["sudo","read","update","create","list"]
allowed_parameters = {
"policies" = [["policy1","policy2","policy3"]]
"*" = []
}
}
```